# A matrix with square diagonals and transpose being increments of other

Tags: java, matrix

> Construct a matrix with the following property:
>
> 1. North-west to South East diagonals are squares.
> 2. Matrix[i][j] + 1 = Matrix[j][i] for each i less than j.

Example of such m a matrix is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720797/whats-the-name-of-this-sort-of-matrix). Also, since it appears this matrix does not have a name, I have named my class "Sqaure Diagonal, Transpose Increment".

Looking for code review, best practices, clever optimzations etc.

```
public final class SquareDiagonalTransposeIncrement {
    
    private SquareDiagonalTransposeIncrement() {} 
    
    
    public static int[][] getSqaureDiagonalTransposeIncrementMatrix (int dimension) {
        if (dimension < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("dimension: " + dimension + " should be greater than 0");
        }
        
        final int[][] m = new int[dimension][dimension];
        
        // set the diagonal
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {
            m[i][i] = (i + 1) * (i + 1);  
        }
        
 
        /*
         * Definition of the quadrant.
         * 
         * - 0th quadrant means a quadrant square matrix from (0,0) to (0,0)
         * - 1st quadrant means a quadrant square matrix from (0,0) to (1,1) 
         * - 2nd quadrant means a quadrant square matrix from (0,0) to (2,2)
         * 
         */
        for (int quadrant = 0; quadrant < dimension - 1; quadrant++) {
            besiegeQuadrant(m, quadrant);
        }
        
        return m;
    }
    
    
    private static void besiegeQuadrant(int[][] m, int quadrant) {
        int value = m[quadrant][quadrant];
        
       // besiege the quadrant from the eastern and southern boundaries.
        for (int i = 0; i <= quadrant; i++) {
            m[i][quadrant + 1] = ++value; // eastern
            m[quadrant + 1][i] = ++value; // southern
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] m =  SquareDiagonalTransposeIncrement.getSqaureDiagonalTransposeIncrementMatrix (4);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{ 1, 2, 5, 10}, m[0]);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{ 3, 4, 7, 12}, m[1]);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{ 6, 8, 9, 14}, m[2]);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[]{11,13,15, 16}, m[3]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Throwing a different spin on the process, I think you are missing an alternate algorithm that produces the same result....

Here is a 'simple' loop that 'works'. It works because it uses a different 'rule' that is based on the pattern that your matrix creates.

The Pattern is obvious when you study the matrix from the bottom-right corner, and work backwards. The initial value is the square of the matrix size. Then you subtract 1 to the left, then another 1 above, and another 1 to the next left, and another 1 to the next above, etc.

```
private static final int[][] buildMagicMatrix(int size) {
    int value = size * size + 1;
    int[][] matrix = new int[size][size];
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        matrix[i][i] = --value;
        for (int d = i - 1; d >= 0; d--) {
            matrix[i][d] = --value;
            matrix[d][i] = --value;
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Using this algorithm you produce results like:

> ```
> Size 9
>     1    2    5   10   17   26   37   50   65
>     3    4    7   12   19   28   39   52   67
>     6    8    9   14   21   30   41   54   69
>    11   13   15   16   23   32   43   56   71
>    18   20   22   24   25   34   45   58   73
>    27   29   31   33   35   36   47   60   75
>    38   40   42   44   46   48   49   62   77
>    51   53   55   57   59   61   63   64   79
>    66   68   70   72   74   76   78   80   81
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that your description uniquely defines the matrix.  However, you can fill the upper-right triangle merely by pattern recognition.  Starting from the diagonal going up, each column is a sequence descending by 2.  From there, just apply the transpose-increment rule.

```
public static int[][] getSqaureDiagonalTransposeIncrementMatrix(int dim) {
    int[][] m = new int[dim][dim];

    // Fill diagonal and upper-right
    for (int row = 0, col = row; row < dim; row = ++col) {
        m[row][col] = (row + 1) * (row + 1);
        for (--row; row >= 0; --row) {
            m[row][col] = m[row + 1][col] - 2;
        }
    }
    // Fill the lower-left using the transpose-increment rule
    for (int row = 0; row < dim; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < row; ++col) {
            m[row][col] = m[col][row] + 1;
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```